# Creating a _.memoize function that takes in a function as a parameter

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, memoization

I just started learning about [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) today and I am having a hard time wrapping my head around it. I am trying to create a memoize function that stores the result of the parameter function that has been called already and return its value instead of calling it again.

This is my code:

```
_.memoize = function(func) {
    var stored = {};

    if (stored.hasOwnProperty('calculated')) {
      return stored['calculated'];
    }

    stored['calculated'] = func;

    return func;
  };
```

The test cases are:

```
var spy = sinon.spy(function() { return 'Dummy output'; });
var memoSpy = _.memoize(spy);
memoSpy(10);
expect(spy).to.have.been.calledOnce;
memoSpy(10);
expect(spy).to.have.been.calledOnce;
```

And:

```
var spy = sinon.spy(function() { return 'Dummy output'; });
var memoSpy = _.memoize(spy);
memoSpy([1, 2, 3]);
expect(spy).to.have.been.calledOnce;
memoSpy([1, 2, 3]);
expect(spy).to.have.been.calledOnce;
```

I thought my stored object stores the result of `func`(?).

The error I am getting is basically saying that 'spy' should have been called once, yet its getting called twice.

Comment: Is this all your code? I don't see *any* place where you're calling `func`...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are returning the original `func`. You have to do some second-order stuff, like:

```
var memoize = function(func) {
  var stored = {};

  return (function() {      
    if (!stored.hasOwnProperty('calculated')) {
      stored['calculated'] = func();
    }

    return stored['calculated'];
  });
};

// To test
var x = function() { console.log('function called'); return 42; }

y = memoize(x)

y()
// => function called
// 42

y()
// 42
```

Where you basically return a modified/extended function that wraps the original `func` and adds the memoizing behavior.

Comment: i added test instructions. if it does not work for you, there must be sth else still wrong